# Opening WhatsApp Web on phones doesn't show QR code and redirects to the homepage instead

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When I open https://web.whatsapp.com on Android phones, there's no QR code to be scanned nor it shows any messages, but instead, it automatically redirects to https://www.whatsapp.com.

[image]

How to make WhatsApp Web shows the QR code on Android phones?

Answer (score 2):

https://web.whatsapp.com/ website is only for laptop or desktop users so that they can use WhatsApp on their laptop or desktop. If you visit this website from your smartphone, it will redirect you to their official website of WhatsApp.

Answer (score 1):

To use WhatsApp Web on Android (which is very handy and widely used):
close all Chrome tabs, open a new incognito window, check the Desktop site version from the menu if not checked, open https://web.whatsapp.com/, et voila: the QR code.

The important thing is to open a *new* tab when you exit from incognito, Chrome deletes all of the cookies! And at the base, there is a problem with cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I use Firefox Browser with User Agent Switcher extension when opening https://web.whatsapp.com/. Furthermore, I select "Request Desktop site" and it works.